# Do flights to/from Hong Kong count as flights to/from China for the purpose of acquiring a Chinese visa?

Tags: visas, china

Round-trip tickets are a requirement to get a Chinese visa for nationals of most countries. Is a flight to/from Hong Kong considered a flight to/from China for the purpose of acquiring a Chinese visa?

If not, is a train reservation between Hong Kong and a city in China sufficient to prove a round trip?

Comment: You can get through trains to HK but the usual exit is to cross the border at Shenzhen and proceed from there. The cheapest way to the airport costs about $10 US total for the subway-like train and the Airbus coach (no reservations possible for either) so they are not likely to be worried about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, a flight to/from Hong Kong is considered "good enough".

Source: I was in this situation last year, and a flight departing from Hong Kong was considered sufficient.  You may be asked to provide a quick written statement of how you plan to travel between mainland China & Hong Kong though.